# Twitter Feed not pulling in on Site // Error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, twitter

**I'm wondering why, within the sidebar of my wordpress theme, This code is not pulling in my latest tweets?**

```
<?php
/*
    PHP Twitter Feed Importer
       @mradamdavies
     www.elevatelocal.co.uk
==-----------------------------*/

class pull_tweets { // Create a basic class

var $twitter_handle;    // Twitter username
var $tweet_limit;       // Max tweets to return
var $tweet_links;       // Show @profile links
var $tweet_tags;        // Show #tag links
var $tweet_avatar;      // Show twitter avatar
var $tweet_profile;     // Show twitter profile link

var $hard_max;          // Real max tweets (Used to filter out @replies)
var $i;                 // Tweet counter

function show_tweet_links($tweet_links_output, $tweet_links) { // Find and replace @replies with links
        if($tweet_links == true) {
            $find  = '/\@([a-zA-Z]+)/';
            $replace  = '<a class="hash_link" href="http://twitter.com/'.strtolower('\1').'" rel="nofollow">@\1</a>';
            $tweet_links_text = preg_replace($find,$replace,$tweet_links_output);
            return $tweet_links_text;
        }
        else { return $tweet_links_output; }
}

function show_hash_tags($tweet_hashtags_output, $tweet_tags) { // Find and replace #tags with links
    if($tweet_tags == true) {
        $find_hash_tag  = '/\#([a-zA-Z]+)/';
        $replace_hash_tag  = '<a class="hash_link" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23'.strtolower('\1').'" rel="nofollow">#\1</a>';
        return
        preg_replace($find_hash_tag,$replace_hash_tag,$tweet_hashtags_output);
    }
    else { return $tweet_hashtags_output; }
}

function show_twitter_avatar($tweet_avatar_output, $tweet_avatar) { // Show avatar
    if($tweet_avatar == true) {
        return '<img src="'.$tweet_avatar_output.'" alt="" />';
    }
    else { return false; }
}

function show_twitter_profile_link($tweet_profile_output, $tweet_profile) { // Insert profile link
    if($tweet_profile == true) {
        return '<a class="profile_link" href="http://twitter.com/'.$tweet_profile_output.'">@'.$tweet_profile_output.'</a>';
    }
    else { return false; }
}

// Create a basic function to pull latest tweets
function tweets($twitter_handle, $tweet_limit, $tweet_links, $tweet_tags, $tweet_avatar, $tweet_profile) {

        /* Store Tweets in a JSON object */
        $tweet_feed =   json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='.
                        $twitter_handle.'&exclude_replies=false&count='.$hard_max));

        $i = 0; // Start the tweet limit counter
        foreach ($tweet_feed as $tweet) { // Loop through the tweets

            if ($tweet->in_reply_to_user_id == '' && $i != $tweet_limit) { // Don't show direct @replies
                ++$i; // Increase tweet counter

    // Check true/false flags and return output accoringly
    $tweet_text = $tweet->text;
    $tweet_text = pull_tweets::show_tweet_links($tweet_text,$tweet_links); // Show @reply links?
    $tweet_text = pull_tweets::show_hash_tags($tweet_text,$tweet_tags); // Show #tag links?
    $twitter_avatar =
pull_tweets::show_twitter_avatar($tweet->user->profile_image_url,$tweet_avatar); // Show avatar?
    $twitter_profile =
    pull_tweets::show_twitter_profile_link($twitter_handle,$tweet_profile); // Show main profile link?

    // Echo our tweet contents
    echo '
    <div class="tweet_bg">',$twitter_avatar,'
    <p>'.$tweet_text.'<br />'.$twitter_profile.'</p>
    </div>';

            }

        } // end of foreach

    } // end of tweets function

} // end of pull_tweets class
?>


<script language="javascript">
$my_tweets = new pull_tweets();

echo $my_tweets->tweets('mradamdavies', 5, true, true, true, true);
</script>
```

*Referred by this tutorial:*
*http://www.elevatelocal.co.uk/blog/php-twitter-feed-importer-05094504*

I want to do this with PHP or minimal JavaScript. Currently Twitter Widgets are not working on my site for some reason.

Comment: Firstly, are there any items in the error log that relate to this? Potentially I can see file_get_contents not being supported with URLs, and quite a few hosts disable allow_url_fopen

Comment: No errors relating in Error Console.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP in your `<script>` isn't getting parsed as PHP. You likely want

```
<?php
$my_tweets = new pull_tweets();

$my_tweets->tweets('mradamdavies', 5, true, true, true, true);
?>
```

As Jamie pointed out, the HTML produced by `tweets()` isn't JavaScript, so you don't need the `<script>` tag at all.

Comment: And also, the echo outputs HTML so you don't need the `script` tags at all. Literally just spotted that about 2 seconds before you

Comment: Thanks Both, but I've tried both suggestions - and still see nothing in the Twitter Feed area...

Comment: @JamieBicknell Good catch! Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, still displays blank. I've also tried it on a stand alone page with all the code provided above and your edit; and still, blank :(